# Mapa Colombia en d3js, datamaps

Tags: d3.js

Por favor, este script no muestra el mapa de colombia, Qué esta mal o falta?

```js
var map = new Datamap({element: document.getElementById('container'),
      scope: 'col'
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
 <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 450px;">&nbsp;</div>

 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.col.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario sobre escribir el método `setProjection`.

```js
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('container'),
  scope: 'col',
  setProjection: function (element) {
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([-68, 4]) // [Longitud, Latitud]
        .scale(1200);
    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    return { path: path, projection: projection };
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 400; height: 550px"></div>

 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.col.js"></script>
```